# Visual Styles for Windows 7 & Vista?

Tags: windows-7, windows, themes

We have softwares like StylesXP and Windowblinds and more freewares that changes visual styles of windows operating system. Stylesxp is unique and it does visual style modification. Note visual styles differ from themes, if you want to have idea about this [check styleXP's official site.](http://www.tgtsoft.com/prod_sxp.php)

(*I don't want skin windowblinds, i'm interested in changing visual styles of windows 7 and vista without any external application*)

**Is it possible to have visual style modification on Windows 7 and Vista? Any pointers for development of those visual styles ?**

Comment: Added the link to StyleXP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need [a theme patcher](http://deepxw.blogspot.com) to use visual styles in Vista and 7 without third party software. There are not many visual styles for 7, [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=818990) are a few. For Vista (and also eventually 7) i really recommend [Deviantart](http://www.deviantart.com/), they have a plethora of styles. [Neowin forums](http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?) has good sections about visual style creation, booth for Vista and 7.